# Deployment Angular Project error type MIME (text/html)

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment, build, mime-types

I try to deploy an Angular/CLI 6.12.0 project.

When I put "dist" folder content on a server, there is a console error 
"type MIME".

```html
Le chargement du module à l’adresse « http://www.sylvainallain.fr/polyfills-es2015.fd917e7c3ed57f282ee5.js » a été bloqué en raison d’un type MIME interdit (« text/html »).
Le chargement du module à l’adresse « http://www.sylvainallain.fr/main-es2015.2fcd6517edb1de962f8a.js » a été bloqué en raison d’un type MIME interdit (« text/html »).
Le chargement du module à l’adresse « http://www.sylvainallain.fr/runtime-es2015.24b02acc1f369d9b9f37.js » a été bloqué en raison d’un type MIME interdit (« text/html »).
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uFyT.png

This in French for me ^^.
You can see it in console here http://biblio.sylvainallain.fr

It's a simply application like a library.
Back-end (logs and data) is manage with Firebase.

In local, all is OK.

I make the build with "ng build --prod", it create a "dist" folder.

My index.html after prod:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bibliothèque Angular</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.735ba4029395bfd97371.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.f9fad3ad3c84e6dbdd72.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.fd917e7c3ed57f282ee5.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.24b02acc1f369d9b9f37.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.2fcd6517edb1de962f8a.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.24b02acc1f369d9b9f37.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="main-es5.2fcd6517edb1de962f8a.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

I find this GitHub post: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325
.This is the same issue, I try some solutions but nothing work.

The issue is only with `es2015.*.js` files. So I think there is an issue with `type="module"` which is not recognize like a Javascript file.
I don't understand why Angular don't manage it.

**Edit** 25 October :

- try to replace `type="module"` with `type="application/javascript"`. Don't work. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606789/angular-8-ng-build-throwing-mime-error-with-cordova?rq=1)
- try to update Angular/CLI & Angular/core with `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty` and `ng build --prod` again. Don't work
- try to host it with Firebase. Same issue: https://bibliang.firebaseapp.com/

Thanks for help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of dist folder in your project workspace. There are two solutions that worked for me :

Sol 1. In your dist folder there may a folder named as your project name move all the files of that folder to the dist folder and then change the dir location to the `dist/index.html` in server.js file.

Move all files from `dist/you_project_name` to `dist/`

Then change the dir location in server.js file 'dist/you_project_name' to 'dist/'

Sol 2. You can change the src attribute of all error causing  tags in index.html file, like ::

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module">
```

changed to

```
<script src="folder_name_inside_the_dist_dir/runtime-es2015.js" type="module">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 <script src="polyfills-es2015.fd917e7c3ed57f282ee5.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.24b02acc1f369d9b9f37.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.2fcd6517edb1de962f8a.js" type="module"></script>

keep all above file in another folder and give path here like

<script src="../../js/polyfills-es2015.fd917e7c3ed57f282ee5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it will work