# Angular 8 - Failed to load module script

Tags: angular

I tried to publish my Angular 8 Web build into the server. The build made successfully. But it starts to show error after publishing in Server. I will list the error below.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I will add a screenshot of the image as well

[image]
I will add my config.xml file here

```
{
    "name": "Project",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
        "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "core-js": "^2.6.11",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "ng-animate-scroll": "^7.1.0",
        "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.3.24",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
        "@types/node": "^8.10.59",
        "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.3",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835

Comment: Or this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606789/angular-8-ng-build-throwing-mime-error-with-cordova

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to create a new ionic project using ionic start command. Copy your src directory and *package.json* file. And just give npm install. Once again add platforms and make sure you have index.html file inside www folder.